# "No such file or directory" after restart

Tags: partitioning, mount, nautilus

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (64 bit)

I have a drive partition shared between my Windows and Ubuntu installations, `/media/malnormalulo/DATA`. When I boot up and attempt to access anything on that partition, it tells me it doesn't exist.

```
malnormalulo@empedocles:~$ ls /media/malnormalulo
malnormalulo@empedocles:~$ ls /media/malnormalulo/DATA
ls: cannot access '/media/malnormalulo/DATA': No such file or directory
```

When I use Nautilus to navigate to "Other Locations", I can see DATA listed. Clicking on it (not even opening it, just selecting it) causes the whole system to begin recognizing the mount until the next reboot.

```
malnormalulo@empedocles:~$ ls /media/malnormalulo
DATA
malnormalulo@empedocles:~$ ls /media/malnormalulo/DATA
[some stuff]
```

This means I have a workaround, but it's awfully inconvenient. How can I get Ubuntu to recognize the mount on its own, or automate whatever Nautilus is doing under the covers?

Comment: Sounds like you may need to add it to FSTAB.